# Best practice for offline web development

Tags: javascript, html, web-services, localhost, local

I am developing a website that I am currently working on the front end javascript and html for. My preference is to work off of osx natively, but I do have Linux and windows installed on my machine.

What would be the best practice to continue to work on the functionality of the front while I do not have an internet connection?

Comment: keyword to search for is "development environment" and yeah, localhost.

Comment: You can start a webserver from command line if using PHP. Otherwise, just run the filepath to index.html in your browser. You will need to download any remote dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do a lot of web development while on plane trips to various customer spaces.  I can tell you my setup, but I will say, everything depends on:

- Your OS
- Your tools
- Your personal preferences

I use Windows as my OS, and I program using Visual Studio.  It uses IIS Express (Cassini) to serve web content on LocalHost.  I can configure the port if I want to and even have SSL support.

I also have IIS 10.0 installed on my machine.  If the project I'm working on is a "serious" long term project, I'll create a local web app with dedicated AppPool and IIS configurations.  I do this to more fully simulate production.

With Visual Studio as my tool, I can configure everything so that with a single click of a button, I can view the changes I've made to my HTML/JavaScript/CSS/LESS

If you aren't using Windows, look into Apache for your web server.  The rest is very similar:

- Create a local web app
- Modify your local HTML/JS/CSS
- Refresh your browser
- Confirm your changes.

Comment: any experience with a similar OSX environment?

Comment: You can check out Visual Studio Code (https://code.visualstudio.com/Download) and you can even build ASP.NET Core applications with it for FREE (https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-mac-aspnet.html)  I use Visual Studio, so that's what I know.  Good luck!\

Answer (score 0):

If you dont use PHP or other server-side languages, then you can do it locally. For PHP I would suggest using WAMP.

Comment: WAMP does run locally though.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a virtual machine to work, your machine is(I assume) perfect and enough for the work. 
Let's say you have a machine running a GNU/Linux OS, only things you need are:

1. Install a web server(Apache/Nginx), I'll go for [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/solutions/web-server/)
2. Create the www/ folder in /var
3. Copy your project in /var/www
4. Set up your server configuration for (virtualhost in case you go for Apache), for nginx (/etc/nginx/sites-avalable) [doc here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html)
5. Happy coding :)